# Thread indexing for image rows / columns in CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

So I'm working on a CUDA program, and I'm experiencing some issues when it comes to indexing blocks and threads. Basically, I'm trying to implement the [Pixel Sort](https://github.com/kimasendorf/ASDFPixelSort) algorithm in CUDA. (With one modification, we are only processing *either* rows or columns, not both at the same time)

The way I was visualizing it was to simply run N blocks with 1 thread each (for the number of rows, or columns) and have each block process that row / column independently of each other.

So if we want to sort on columns, we launch the kernel like this (there are a couple extra parameters that are only relevant to our specific processing, so I've left them out for simplicity)

```
pixel_sort<<<cols, 1>>>(d_image, d_imageSort, rows, cols, ...);
```

Then in the kernel, I access the block index with

```
int tid = blockIdx.x;
```

This allows me to work with one row / columns data per block, but it has some issues. It's running slower than our serial implementation of the algorithm for smaller images, and straight up crashes when the image size becomes too large.

An alternative thread scheme I was considering would be to map each of the image's pixels to one thread, however I have a couple of questions on this.

1. If we were to launch N blocks with M threads, representing N cols with M rows, how do we avoid 512 (or 1024 ?) limit of threads per block. Can we just have each thread process multiple pixels in the column in this instance? How would the indexing look like in the kernel?
2. The algorithm basically requires that we work on the entire column, hence each thread cannot *just* do some work on that pixel, they have to communicate, presumably using shared memory. Would it be a valid strategy to have one "master" thread per block, that does the actual sorting calculations, and then have all of the other threads participate in the shared memory?

Other Notes:

- Our image data is read in through OpenCV, and has the RGBA values stored in a `uchar4` array

Answer (score 3):

If you have a single thread per block, you very quickly run into thread occupancy issues.  If your goal is to do a full row sort (for columns you could transpose the image before sending to the GPU to take advantage of global coalescing), the fastest way that gets a decent result is probably to do a radix or merge-sort on a per-row basis, basically copying the steps from http://mgarland.org/files/papers/nvr-2008-001.pdf.  You could assign k blocks of m threads each for each row such that km >= image width.  Then you would be launching k*(image height) blocks.  Your grid would then be of size (k, height, 1).

As for your specific questions:

1. You cannot get around the 512/1024 thread-per-block limit, you would have to restructure your algorithm.
2. A "master" thread would generally be poor design, causing stalls, overhead, and not taking full advantage of the many cores.  You may sometimes need to utilize a single thread, say to output/broadcast a result, but mostly you want to avoid it.  See the linked article for sample algorithms that mostly avoid this.